# HTML table Scraping in PHP and DOM

Tags: php, mysql, dom, web-crawler

I am trying to pull the students results from school result server and store it inside the local database. I have the following html file. I want to scrape the html table data and store it in the mysql database as shown below the code.
I want help regarding how to parse the html DOM and store it inside mysql. As there are so many  tags I am not able to differentiate between them.

```html
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td>Name: Shanthini</td>
        <td>Reg.No: 12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Maths</td>
        <td>89</td>
        <td>Pass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>Pass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chemistry</td>
        <td>89</td>
        <td>Pass</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to store like this:

[image: I want to store like this]

Can anyone help me in this type of crawling using php and mysql

Comment: What problem are you faced?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Have a look at SimpleXML (http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) which might give you a start point.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you only need to do once and you know basic jquery and basic css selectors you can use QueryPath https://github.com/technosophos/querypath

Load the html and use techniques similar to what you would do in jquery but with the QueryPath object.

If you know actual DOM manipulation techniques and have node.js installed that might be even easier to use.